# In SSR rendering, executing pop() on asynchronously retrieved data does not yield the correct results

Tags: arrays, vuejs3, slice, vite, server-side-rendering

```js
const resAdv = await getHomeAdvertisement()
resAdv.data.data.pop()
console.log(resAdv.data.data) // 2
```

```js
const resAdv = await getHomeAdvertisement()
setTimeout(() => {
  resAdv.data.data.pop()
  console.log(resAdv.data.data) // 3
}, 3000)
```

```js
const resAdv = await getHomeAdvertisement()
resAdv.data.data = resAdv.data.data.slice(0, 3)
console.log(resAdv.data.data) // 3
```

`getHomeAdvertisement()` returns an array with a length of 4.

Clearly, the second and third code segments produce the correct results. I'm unsure why the length becomes 2 after applying `pop()` in the first code segment. Moreover, the results become correct when a `setTimeout()` is added. I suspect it may be due to asynchronous issues. However, I cannot determine why there isn't a problem when using `slice()`. Please help me. Thank you.